# create a python module with C and Python code

Tags: python, c

I have a small python module I have created with the Python C API which I call mycore.

I have also created some utility scripts in Python which are related.

How can I put both in the same module namespace?  I know I can call Python code from my C code but surely there is an easier way to do that.

Thanks

Comment: Did you play around with boost python?

Comment: I'm quite happy with the C API

Comment: I have the same question.

Answer (score 3):

The obvious way is by making `mycore` a package. Create a `mycore/__init__.py` that imports both the C part, typically named something like `_mycore`, and the Python part:

```
from _mycore import *
from _mycorepy import *
```

In the same directory you'd have a `_mycore.so` and `_mycorepy.py`.

Another way to mix Python and C code is by invoking `PyRun_String` on the embedded Python. This might be what you mean by *I know I can call Python code from my C code...*, but just in case, here is a simple example with the potentially tricky refcounting details:

```c
PyObject *get_factory()
{
  PyObject *g, *runret, *factory;
  // prepare a dictionary for the module to run in
  g = Py_BuildValue("{s:O}", "__builtins__", PyEval_GetBuiltins());
  if (!g)
    return NULL;
  // run Python code in the dictionary -- the code may import modules, etc.
  runret = PyRun_String("\
def factory():\n\
    return 42\n", Py_file_input, g, NULL);
  Py_XDECREF(runret);
  if (!runret) {
    Py_DECREF(g);
    return NULL;
  }
  Py_DECREF(runret);
  // pick the stuff you care about from the dictionary and return it
  factory = PyDict_GetItemString(g, "factory");
  Py_INCREF(factory);
  Py_DECREF(g);
  return factory;
}
```

Comment: Is this the best resource for learning about packages?  http://guide.python-distribute.org/creation.html  Also, why the underscore before the mycore* ?

Comment: @user3275885 The link appears to be about distributing on PyPI and others. The answer refers to [Python packages](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages), which are simply modules spread into several files, defined by a directory with `__init__.py`. The underscore in `_mycore` signifies that `mycore._mycore` is an implementation detail of the `mycore` package, and not something the user of the package should be importing themselves.

Comment: the PyRun_String() will surely work, but I was hoping to avoid any extra "glue" .  Thank you @user4815162342

Answer (score 0):

OK, this worked for me.  My circumstances may be different.  My C module was built internally and provided to my embedded Python with a call to PyImport_AppendInittab().

But I still had some accompanying Python code that I wanted associated with the same namespace.

So I got it working by naming my C code _mygadget and the Python file mygadget.py.  For the first line of mygadget.py I wrote:

```
from _mygadget import *
```

This seems to work.  I don't know what would happen if I had a Python method and C call with the same name.  I am avoiding that at present.